# Verifying whether a view method is called or not in Android Studio Testing (JUnit and mockito)

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, android-testing

Sorry for silly questions, I am new to Testing in Android studio and not able to find solutions online.
Well I am trying to verify that a method in view is called whenever the method in presenter is called or not.

```
    @Override
    public void chooseImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        view.galleryImageSelected(intent);
    }
```

The above snippet is a method in my Presenter Class, and as you can see, I am calling a interface method of view from this function.
Now I have to verify/test that this snippet works perfectly.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private File storageDir;
    @Mock
    private PackageManager pManager;
    @Mock
    private Context appContext;
    @Mock
    private MainActivityContract.View view;
    @InjectMocks
    private MainActivityPresenter presenter;
    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Intent> captor;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        presenter = new MainActivityPresenter(storageDir, pManager, appContext, view);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCallIntentWhenClickedOnCameraClickButton() throws IOException {

        presenter.chooseImage();
        verify(view).galleryImageSelected(captor.capture());
        Intent intent = captor.getValue();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        assertThat(action, is(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT));
        assertThat(type, is("image/*"));
    }

}
```

Now to verify view's method, I have to pass the intent in galleryImageSelected() method, but as intent was a local variable, how do I test this? Do I have to mock the variable intent and then pass, and if yes how to mock an intent variable.

Also if I am doing the following thing:

```
   @Test
    public void shouldCallIntentWhenClickedOnCameraClickButton() throws IOException {
        presenter.chooseImage();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        verify(view).galleryImageSelected(intent);
    }
```

I am getting the following error while testing:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
view.galleryImageSelected(null);
-> at com.example.imagepicker.ExampleUnitTest.shouldCallIntentWhenClickedOnCameraClickButton(ExampleUnitTest.java:52)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock local variable but you can capture the argument passed, using [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html) and then validate argument as -

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PresenterTest {

  @Mock
  private View view;
  @InjectMocks
  private Presenter presenter;

  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<Intent> captor;

  @Test
  public void shouldCallIntentWhenClickedOnCameraClickButton() {
    presenter.chooseImage();
    verify(view).galleryImageSelected(captor.capture());
    Intent intent = captor.getValue();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();
    assertThat(action, is(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT));
    assertThat(type, is("image/*"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Pankaj, I am getting an error at assertThat line:                       
 java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: is "android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"
     but: was null
Expected :is "android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"
Actual   :null

Comment: Do you store 'action' in intent ? Idea is, you can capture intent, which is created as local variable in method, and then validate state of intent.

Comment: Yup, I got your point regarding capturing the argument and then validating that the argument is correct/wrong. But when I am trying to do intent.getAction(), it is returning NULL. And yes, I have set the action to ACTION_GET_CONTENT, as you could see in my main thread code.

Comment: After debugging, I found that intent in itself is null, that is captor.getValue() is returning NULL

Comment: I hope you have mocked View. Also, annotate your class with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class). I have edited my answer to show complete code.

Comment: Yes, I have already mocked the view and also annotated my class before. I have also updated my UnitTest code in the main thread, still I am getting Intent as null.